# How to send post data json to api using retrofit getting response as object

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

Postman description:

[image: Postman description]

Interface:

```
public interface PostService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/user/login")
    Call<User> login(@Body User user);
}
```

Call function:

```
User user = new User("student", "student@gmail.com");
Call<User> noticeList = RetrofitAPI.getService().login(user);

noticeList.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        Log.i("postdata", "v =" + response.body().getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityLogin.this, "Server taking time try refreshing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

How can we send json post data to server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `Call<User> login(@Body User user);` with your response model class like `Call<YOURRESPONSEMODEL> login(@Body User user);` and change your `call function` according. To create a response model use your response from postman and create your model [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create Pojo class:

```
public class SubscriptionResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("mNo")
    @Expose
    private String mNo;

    @SerializedName("pId")
    @Expose
    private String pId;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;

    public String getPId() {
        return pId;
    }

    public void setPId(String pId) {
        this.pId = pId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

Then, create interface:

```
@POST("subs?")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<SubscriptionResponseModel> setSubs(@Field("pId") String pId,
                                        @Field("mNo") String mNo,
                                        @Field("status") String status);
```

Get Retrofit instance:

```
private static Retrofit getSubsRetrofitInstance() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(GlobalVar.BASE_URL) 
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
}
```

In `getApiService`:

```
public static ApiService getSubsApiService() {
    return getSubsRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
}
```

Now, call function:

```
ApiService apiService = getSubsApiService();
Call<SubscriptionResponseModel> subcriptionResponse = apiService.setSubs("1", "1", "y");

subcriptionResponse.enqueue(new Callback<SubscriptionResponseModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SubscriptionResponseModel> call, Response<SubscriptionResponseModel> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            /////print success message
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SubscriptionResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```